# Green Tree python refuses to eat

Tags: feeding, snakes

I've had a green tree python for about a year now. She has been eating really well with no illnesses other than constipation when I first got her. However for the past few months she has been grounding herself frequently (2-3 days out of the week) and refusing to eat any mice. It has me concerned because nothing in her environment has changed and she is starting to get skinny. I've tried force-feeding her the head of a pinky mouse but she just regurgitated it. I could stick my hand in her mouth without her biting down on my hand or fingers. There is no physical signs of any illnesses. No redness, puss, nor any weird shaped teeth or other obvious deformities.

What can I do as far as feeding so she stops losing weight? Why is she not eating for these few months?

She is 4.5 feet long. Temperature averages at about 86 degrees Fahrenheit using a UV pad. I have a mister that sprays the cage 30 seconds every 2 hours. Humidity ~60 percent at all times. Been feeding adult mice. Cage is 3×3×3ft custom cage with plenty of varying perches.

Comment: you have to take the snake to a vet and take it from there and ask for advice here after you have been at the vet,it sounds like you know what you are doing and have the right setup.

Comment: When was the last shed? I would say go to the vet, could be impacted? Has it been going to the toilet?

Comment: Last time it went to the restroom was about a month ago. A month after it last ate. She last shed about a month ago as well. I set up a vet appointment and will give an update in a couple of days.